# Having trouble doing simple numeric comparisons with Django

Tags: django

I am trying to compare two numbers, but I get the following error:

```
Could not parse the remainder: '{{hole.number}}' from '{{hole.number}}'
```

Here is my code:

```
  {% if (hole.number - 1) > 0 %}
    ...
  {% endif %}
```

hole.number is a positive integer, so the comparison should be valid.

Comment: There's a very large note about the philosophy at the top of the [template documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/templates/), which explains clearly why things like this won't work.

Comment: {% if hole.number > 1 %} ? :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might work, but to be honest **you are best doing this in your view if you can or otherwise in a template tag**

```
{% with hole.number|add:"-1" as num %}
 {% if num > 0 %}
 ...
 {% endif %}
{% endwith %}
```